# Не получается сделать push на bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Создал проект на bitbucket. Теперь хочу залить туда свои файлы из локальной папки. Проверяю текущий статус:

> On branch master
>    nothing to commit, working directory clean

Хотя папка полна файлов. Как можно отправить мои файлы?

Comment: `git add ...`, `git commit` в локальной папке выполнены?

Comment: а вы подключили этот репозиторий на bitbucket как `remote` в своём локальном репозитории?

Comment: Да скорее всего вы забыли `git add --all` затем `git commit -m "ваш комментарий"` и потом только `git push origin`

Comment: Сообщение не говорит вам о том, что нечего отправить; сообщение говорит вам, что файлов, которые вы, возможно, незакоммитили, не существуют. Однако коммиты в этот момент существуют только на вашей машине, для того, чтобы отправить их на сервер, надо сделать `git push`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: а в SVN ведь командой `commit` заливаются на сервер файлы? Подозреваю тут SVN-акцент.

Answer (score 3):

> On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean

Это сообщение означает что вы не выбрали файлы для коммита. Попробуйте

```
git add .
git commit
```

это добавит все ваши файлы, и вкоммитает их в локальный репозиторий. после этого:

```
git push
```

для отправки изменений в удаленный репозиторий.

Comment: A "working directory clean" означает, что уже всё закоммитили, новых изменений нет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, но от add / commit топикастеру хуже не станет, а тому, кто придет позже в точно такой же ситуации с чуть другим сообщением - может быть поможет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, уточнение читающим комментарии: «... новых изменений нет среди *отслеживаемых* файлов».

Answer (score 3):

> On branch master
>    nothing to commit, working directory clean

Это означает, что:

1. Ничего не добавлено к следующему коммиту (индекс пустой, c момента последнего коммита [`git add`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431839/181472) не было).
2. И добавлять нечего, изменений после прошлого коммита не было.

Если вы уже подключили удаленный репозиторий, можете делать `git push`.

Если еще не подключили, откройте ваш проект на Bitbucket, там будет инструкция с точными командами. Инструкция очень простая, выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]